# Multiple values fetched when try to get the azure web app objectid

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get web app objectid using powershell but multiple objectid fetched in the result.

```
$app = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "devt002"
$app.ObjectId
```

Result :

```
33b7cfc5-ca71-412a-ac3b-8b0ca49fb8a6
976a5114-4fab-4b5a-ab92-7403ef25ac29
```

The original objectid is '976a5114-4fab-4b5a-ab92-7403ef25ac29'.

Comment: You have 2 service principals that match the search. You can check their DisplayName to see what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing strange, as mentioned in the comment, you have two service principals match the search.

If you want to get the service principal named `devt002`, try the command below.

```
$app = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "devt002" | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "devt002"}
$app.ObjectId
```

**Update**:

Try the command as below, the `$objectid` is what you want.

```
$webapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "<resource group name >" -Name "<web app name>"
$objectid = $webapp.Identity.PrincipalId
```

Comment: still gives me 2 values. how to check number of service principal associated to 'devt002'.

Comment: any other way to do this? I found AZ command to acheive this. 'az webapp show -g devt002RG -n devt002' but the challenge is to retrive the value from json output inside CLI.

Comment: @rAJ I am confused, actually what do you want to do? web app and the service principal are not the same things.

Comment: I need to get the web app object id.

Comment: @rAJ I suppose you enable the `System assigned Identity` for your web app? You want to get the object id of the service principal which was generated automatically?

Comment: @rAJ See my update, make sure you have installed the [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-1.5.0) powershell module.

Comment: Perfect. Works fine in cloud shell. But when i run it in VSTS azure powershell, it show error message - The term 'Get-AzWebApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. Any idea why it is giving this error.

Comment: @rAJ It means you have not installed the `Az` module as I mentioned in the above comment, but I am not familiar with VSTS...

Comment: @rAJ If you have installed the `AzureRM` powershell module in the VSTS, you can also use the old command `Get-AzureRmWebApp` instead of `Get-AzWebApp`.